# Is there a program to accelerate/slowdown time in other process?

Tags: linux, time

Is there a program/library that allows to override time flow in other processes?

Expecting it to override clock_gettime, gettimeofday, alarm and other functions that report time or use timeout using LD_PRELOAD and allows user to change coefficient between real time and virtual time on the fly.

Comment: If you'd want to do so for a whole machine, the easy solution is to create a fake NTP server (not synchronized) and give it a very high drift value.

Comment: No, it's mostly to influence things like games (slowdown or accelerate them). Already implemented simple version, wondering may be there is normal version somewhere.

Comment: Oh, that's yet another matter. Those typically run off `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, not `CLOCK_REALTIME`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed (my hack overrides only CLOCK_MONOTONIC and gettimeofday).

Comment: https://github.com/vi/timeskew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implemented myself (for Linux): https://github.com/vi/timeskew